# why input text not deleted when press back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I make a simple demo in which I restrict pop up screen not to close when back button press .But I am able to do that but when I write something on text field I am not able to delete text.
can we do both thing ? mean restrict pop up screen as well as delete text from the text field ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Show Popup</a>

    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" data-dismissible='false'>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="testCaseIDValue">TestCase Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="testCaseIDValue" id="testCaseInnerIDValue" value="" class="inputTextTestCase"/>
    </div>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" id="doneInnerPopUp" class="common-button">Done</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

js Code

```
$('body').keydown(function(e) {

    if($('#myPopup').is(':visible')) {
        if(e.keyCode == 8) { // 8 is backspace
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just disabled the backspace for the entire document (in your case body), including the input.
To not affect the input, you can check if it is the active element in the condition

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if( 
        $('#myPopup').is(':visible') && 
        (!$('#myPopup input').is(':focus')) &&
        e.which === 8
    ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a4z75/1/)

Comment: your code is working fine ..but if I have 100 text field with different Id..how can I achieve this ..

Comment: can I add 100 textfield id

Comment: You can add as many ID's as you want, as long as they are all unique, but that seems like a lot of work, so you could be a little more sneaky and use jQuery instead, edited the code above.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to create hidden `input` of type `reset`
lets say it has an `id` of `clearIt`

and you can say like :

```
$('body').keydown(function(e) {

    if($('#myPopup').is(':visible')) {
        if(e.keyCode == 8) { // 8 is backspace
           $('#clearIt').trigger("click");       
 }
    }

});
```

it will reset the input text **when it is on a form**